# rviz2 dyld: Library not loaded: @rpath/libIrrXML.dylib

Tags: ros, ros2, rviz, macbook

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I've carefully followed the instructions to install ros2 foxy on MacOs (Mohave) and sourced the ~/ros2_foxy/ros2-osx/setup.bash file.

When I run rviz2 I get the following error:

```
dyld: Library not loaded: @rpath/libIrrXML.dylib
  Referenced from: /usr/local/opt/assimp/lib/libassimp.5.dylib
  Reason: image not found
Abort trap: 6
```

Could someone assist me in resolving this?  Thank you.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/366005/rviz2-dyld:-library-not-loaded:-@rpath/libirrxml.dylib/) by [mjwhite](https://answers.ros.org/users/39136/mjwhite/) on ROS Answers with karma: 91 on 2020-11-19

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

So I had omitted to disable SIP on the Macbook which prevented it from loading the Dynamic Link Libraries.

---

Originally posted by [mjwhite](https://answers.ros.org/users/39136/mjwhite/) with karma: 91 on 2020-11-22

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0